# How to change the background image of my website everytime i click each link or url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

Ok so, I've seen so many questions on the web about this but it seems that many of it is using PHP, ASP, JQUERY and any other languages. For me I am only a little bit familiar with CSS and Java Script and that is the language I only knew. So can someone show me some code of CSS and Java Script for that question?

Anyway, I am also interested in Background on the website that will change every refresh!

Thanks in Advance!

Hey I found the sample code and it is perfectly working!

Credits to this forum: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design-html-and-css/threads/228324/load-different-background-image-when-user-refresh

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
var myImages = ["Background/Background.jpg", "Background/Background2.jpg", "Background/Background3.jpg", "Background/Background4.jpg", "Background/Background5", "Background/Background6", "Background/Background7"];
var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
}
window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.bg {background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:top right;}
</style>
</head>
<body class="bg">
<p>Some text</p>
<!-- put a lot text lines here to see that the background stays fixed. -->
<p>Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: If you are using a new image everytime you refresh, than you are killing your website beauty + you are annoying your users by increasing the page loading time

Comment: Hi! Mr. Alien My Website in functioning via LAN, I mean it is functioning within shared networks or computers. :D So basically page loading is not an issue. That is the reason why I am interested on this work.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of solution :

Store all the files in a folder.

1. Index the images in a database table with a index number. Generate a random number with specific range and display the image which corresponds to the random number
2. Rename all the images in the folder from (1 - n). Generate random number and append with /.

Once you get the random image, you can easily over write the background or any other dom component with javascript like

```
document.getElementByTag('body').setAttribute('style','background-image:url('+<your image>+'));
```

You can simplify it with jQuery too.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using JQuery - just define click event for each of the link -

```
$(function(){
    $("link1").click(function(){
        $("body").css({background-image:"url('link1_image.gif')"}); 
    });
});​
```

For random image load on each refresh you can directly call onload function and set random image.

```
$(function(){        
    var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
    $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
});​
```

Hopefully it will work. Thanks.